# Finding maximum number of edge-disjoint path in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching, directed-acyclic-graphs

How can I find the maximum number of edge-disjoint path in a directed graph . the graph is unweighted.
Suppose the graph is like follow ...

`1 - 2 , 1 - 3 , 4 - 1 , 5 - 1`

So there is two edge disjoint paths in the graph, `4->1->2` and `5->1->3`

How can I solve the problem using matching algorithm ?

My problem is ... suppose i have a directed graph(may contain cycle).
if i put a 'guard' at a node it can start it's journey from that node.
The guard may visit any city multiple times even the cities that are already visited by other guards.
The objective is to find the minimum number of guards to secure all the nodes.

Comment: You'll have maximum number of edge-disjoint paths if each path consists of single edge (number of paths = number of edges).

Comment: I agree with Evgeny Kluev.  I think you need to clarify your question to fully explain your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Counting all paths:*

- Start with all the edges in the graph as your list of available edges.
- While there are still available edges, keep extracting paths and counting them.

*Extracting a path:*

- Remove the first (or any) available edge and call it your current path.
- Try to match your current path's start or end to an available edge's end or start.
- If no available edge matches, then this path is finished.
- If an available edge can lengthen the path, then add it to your current path, remove that edge from the list of available edges, and keep trying to lengthen the path.

Comment: Good answer, only, I fail to see why your solution would be a matching algorithm. :)

Comment: @Gabor-Csardi: I believe the "matching" happens when trying to lengthen each path: the current path is "matched" to an available edge.  Actually, the question's reference to a "matching algorithm" was key in leading me to this understanding of the question. :-)